# Complete beginner with Elif [Python]

Tags: python, if-statement

I tried to do the first assignment from http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/12974/

```
g = int(raw_input('Enter the grade you scored: '))
if g >= 90 & g <= 100:
 print 'Your grade is: A'
elif g >= 80 & g < 90:
 print 'Your grade is: B'
elif g >= 70 & g < 80: 
 print 'Your grade is: C'
elif g >= 60 & g < 70:
 print 'Your grade is: D'
elif g >= 50 & g < 60:
 print 'Your grade is: E' 
elif g >= 0 & g <= 49:
 print 'Your grade is: F'
else:
 print 'You can only enter an integer within the range of 0-100.'
```

The problem is that whenever I run this program, any number I input that is greater than 0 will get:

Your grade is: A

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Bi Rico's answer is simple and correct. To explain the situation further:

- The `&` operator computes the bitwise AND of two integers. For example, `5 & 3 == 1`.
- The precedence of `&` is above the comparison operators (such as `<` and `>=`). So `a < b & c < d` actually means `a < (b & c) < d`.
- Python allows chained comparisons. For example, `a < b == c >= d` translates into `a < b and b == c and c >= d`.

Putting these facts together, this is what happens when you run your program:

- Assume that `g` is assigned an integer value between `0` and `100`, inclusive.
- So the if-test `g >= 90 & g <= 100` means `(g >= (90 & g)) and ((90 & g) <= 100)`.
- Bitwise AND is always smaller than or equal to both arguments (i.e. `(a & b <= a) and (a & b <= b)`).
- Thus `90 & g <= g` is always true. Likewise, `90 & g <= 100` is always true, because `90 <= 100`.
- Therefore the first if-test is always true, so the body will execute and the elif/else clauses will never execute.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is that you're using `&` when you want to use `and`, try this:

```
if g >= 90 and g <= 100:
    print 'Your grade is: A'
...
```

Comment: Well that was easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code you had their was spot on but syntax is very important in Python. You want to use and where you have & like this:

```
g = int(raw_input('Enter the grade you scored: '))
if g >= 90 and g <= 100:
   print 'Your grade is: A'
elif g >= 80 and g < 90:
   print 'Your grade is: B'
elif g >= 70 and g < 80: 
   print 'Your grade is: C'
elif g >= 60 and g < 70:
   print 'Your grade is: D'
elif g >= 50 and g < 60:
   print 'Your grade is: E' 
elif g >= 0 and g <= 49:
   print 'Your grade is: F'
else:
    print 'You can only enter an integer within the range of 0-100.'
```

This will display what you need the correct way.

Answer (score -1):

Using the correct keyword is always important as certain things can cause errors. Use and, not &.